# Location Service using Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to check the location and store the required data in the internal storage of the mobile. To stop this task, use has to tap stop button in the main ui. As this task started, no matter the state of the app, that task should do its work.

I can implement this using native android command. But I want to implement this using cordova and I can't figure out a way to do this..

If this task cannot be done using cordova, can I do it using native android and inject to the cordova app..??

Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the [ng-cordova geolocation](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/geolocation/) watcher, it watches geolocation properties such as lat, lon, and speed.

first intall ng-cordova and inject it

```
bower install ngCordova

angular.module('myApp', ['ngCordova'])
```

then install the geolocation plugin

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.geolocation
```

then you want to create a watcher, make sure to fire it after a device ready event or it will cause problems

This is what device ready function looks like

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
  $cordovaPlugin.someFunction().then(success, error);
}, false);
```

here is the watcher controller:

```
module.controller('GeoCtrl', function($cordovaGeolocation) {


  var watchOptions = {
    frequency : 1000,
    timeout : 3000,
    enableHighAccuracy: false // may cause errors if true
  };

  var watch = $cordovaGeolocation.watchPosition(watchOptions);
  watch.then(
    null,
    function(err) {
      // error
    },
    function(position) {
      var lat  = position.coords.latitude
      var long = position.coords.longitude
  });


  watch.clearWatch();
  // OR
  $cordovaGeolocation.clearWatch(watch)
    .then(function(result) {
      // success
      }, function (error) {
      // error
    });
});
```

As you watch their geolocation info you can push it into a local database like http://pouchdb.com/ or couch db or a server database. If you want to use this in any state of the app you can make it into a service,
here is an example in a app i built

```
service.watchSpeed = function () {
        console.log('watcher');
        ionic.Platform.ready(function () {
            var watchOptions = {
                frequency: 15 * 60 * 1000,
                timeout: 1 * 60 * 1000,
                enableHighAccuracy: true // may cause errors if true
            };

            service.watch = $cordovaGeolocation.watchPosition(watchOptions);
            service.watch.then(
                null,
                function (err) {
                    service.watchSpeed();
                },
                function (position) {
                    if (service.maxspeed.ToUseApp !== 0) {
                        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
                        var long = position.coords.longitude;
                        var speed = position.coords.speed;
                        service.speed = speed;
                        if (speed > service.maxspeed.ToUseApp) {
                            $state.go('overspeed');
                        }
                        if ($ionicHistory.currentStateName() === 'overspeed' && speed < service.maxspeed.ToUseApp) {
                            $ionicHistory.goBack();
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log('speed watcher has been killed, why master??');
                    }
                });
        });
    };
```

then in my home controller i call the watcher

```
ionic.Platform.ready(function () {
                ffService.getMaxSpeed();
            });
```

Comment: Is there a way to check whether this service has started already..?

Comment: Yeah see where is put my console log (watcher)  that tells you when the geowatcher has started.

Comment: I have this kind of a problem. User start this service and close the app without stopping the service. After that user open the app again and try to start service again. Then I have to inform the user that this service is already stated.. How can I do such a thing..?
I'm very new to cordova, please help..

Comment: Just bind a factory variable like service.started in the geowatcher. Then on whatever page you are showing check to see if service.started is true or false.

Comment: I am about to head to class but I can add a example if this later if you would like